# Half empty blank model being appended onto collection on partial render

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have, simply:

#### messages.haml

```
= @messages.count # returns 5
= render partial: 'message', collection: @messages
```

#### message.haml

```
= message.user
= message.body
= message.created_at
```

In the above, five partials are not rendered, but SIX, and the last *ghost* partial contains a model that is half mapped. It returns a `user` (same `user` as previous messages) and returns `nil` for `body` and `created_at`. I have checked the database to be absolutely sure. There are five associations, it outputs five in the view, why it is rendering six?

How do I even debug something seemingly impossible like this?

Comment: Try `length` and `size` in place of `count`. Sometimes they differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure that the partial is rendered 6 times. Put some code in message.haml like this:

```
- puts "\n\n\nrendering template\n\n\n"
```

I have a feeling that You will see this output only 5 times and something else is rendering the last one.

Also before rendering partials, output (inspect) @messages object.

Comment: Thanks. The partial is being rendered six times, but `inspect` has shown me the array of messages contains an extra partial model that `count` didn't pick up (`size` did as per comment on question). Now to go hunting for why that is happening! Love refactoring other people's code :)